# Any ways to obtain the download logs of Google Drive for Work with API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am on Google Apps unlimited license, and I am trying to obtain the download log of both domain user and external user via Google API. I have tried the Activities List API of Admin SDK to obtain the activities logs but according to the following man page

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/drive-event-names

the download event properties is not included in the API result. However, is there any API that allow me get the download log?

Or if there are any other ways, such as using 3rd party Google Drive Addon, any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that there is an audited activity for downloads: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/drive-event-names